# How to fetch data from external website (google data api) related to page keywords and display in sidebar

Tags: dynamic, drupal, web-scraping

There is a Worpdress plugin, which makes for a great example, that does exactly what I am asking, called Vikispot. However, I would like to use Google Data API as the source of the data for Videos, Blogs, News, etc... then just like Vikispot, display the data on my website in a sidebar. Vikispot does the job as far as displaying data from other websites that are related to the keywords in a blog on website, in a sidebar. Although I would like the same code that Vikispot is using and implement this into my drupal based website.

I have searched all over the place and cannot find an answer. I hope it isn't right under my nose =]

Answer (score 0):

[Google Data API 2.0](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html) supports an Atom-format RSS interface.

Use the RSS variant of Google Data API with any RSS feed reader widget. There are dozens..